# magit equivalent to `git push -u origin newLocalBranch`

Tags: magit, git

I often create new branches locally (e.g., *newLocalBranch*), and then push them to the upstream remote origin, thus creating a new remote branch, using `git push -u origin newLocalBranch`. Is there a `magit` function equivalent to this operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`magit-push-current-to-pushremote` actually works perfect for me. If the branch already exists upstream, `magit-push-current-to-pushremote` will just push the committed changes upstream. If the branch does not yet have an upstream location set, `magit-push-current-to-pushremote` will prompt to select a remote location from the minibuffer (e.g., *origin*) to the branch to, defaulting to the same local name (i.e., *newLocalBranch*). Using `magit-push`, instead, would fail because no upstream location has been set for the *newLocalBranch* yet.

Per the documentation for `magit-push-current-to-pushremote`:

> Push the current branch to ‘branch.<name>.pushRemote’.
> If that variable is unset, then push to ‘remote.pushDefault’.
>
> When ‘magit-push-current-set-remote-if-missing’ is non-nil and
> the push-remote is not configured, then read the push-remote from
> the user, set it, and then push to it.

Comment: IIRC if you register the remote via `magit` it also offers to set the option and then the standard push does it too.

Comment: Please explain how that answers the question. Say what it does, for example.

Comment: If this is `P p` I don't see `-u` in the log, just `-v`.